# Is is possible to call watch() on an input ref in Vue 3 to watch the input's value attribute?

Tags: vue.js, watch, ref

I know that we can use the `v-model` directive on an `<input>` element and use `watch()` to trigger a function when the state of the `<input>`'s `value` attribute changes.

I'm trying, however, to watch an `<input>` `ref`.  When I do, the watcher's function is executed when the element is mounted to the DOM, but does not trigger when the `<input>`'s `value` attribute changes.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
<script setup>
    import { ref, watch, watchEffect } from 'vue'

    const refA = ref(null)

    watch(refA, () => {
        console.log('refA changed')
        console.log(refA)
        console.log(refA.value)
        console.log(refA.value.value)
    }, { deep: true })

</script>

<template>
    <input ref="refA" type="text" value="test" /> <br />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, template refs can be watched, but they only fire when the `.value` changes - that's the value of the ref, i.e. the HTML element, not the value of a HTML input element. That fits with what you describe, the watcher firing once at mount and never again. Also, it is not possible to deep-watch a HTML element.

It is fascinating to me how different template refs and data felt in Vue 2, when apparently the mechanism on script-side was always the same, which is now made obvious in Vue 3 composition API. But they still do different things, where one gives access to a HTML element or a Vue component instance, and the other stores a value. I guess the big difference comes from using a ref in the `ref` attribute, not from the way it is declared.

Anyway, if you want to bind to the value of an input, use `v-model` (or `v-bind:modelValue` and `@update:modelValue`), but if you need access to the node for whatever reason, use `ref=`. If you want to do both, you need to use both, it is not possible to use just the template ref.

Comment: One cannot watch a DOM element's properties using a element's ref as the source for a watcher. DOM elements are explicitly skipped over when the watcher traverses a source.  https://github.com/vuejs/core/commit/62b8f4a39ca56b48a8c8fdf7e200cb80735e16ae#diff-59e3ee98b310f26c42283eaed3c0d4b53eee884d097d9fa89b7e1b546453b411

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. if you don't need to use `v-model` then you should use `v-bind` and emit the input event, like the below.

```
<template>
  <input :value="refA" type="text" @input="refA = $event.target.value" /> <br />
</template>
```

This will trigger watch on every update to your input.

A template ref which you have used as part of your example cannot be used to watch the internal value of the component.See below comments thread regarding the same.

Comment: Have a look at [Template Refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html)

Comment: @MoritzRingler right, my bad...i recall now that i have used this on form elements at times..

Comment: Your updated answer also has some issues. Template `ref` is used to make a reference to a template element (the input element in this case), but you are replacing it with the input value, which does not make sense.

Comment: @IgorMoraru i do agree that it is not what i would do, but per the question asked, is there any other way to watch the value of the ref as requested ?

Comment: @thezohaan you can watch the `ref` value, like the OP did. but you cannot watch the internal state of the component through a template `ref`, because that will require the `ref` to be reactive, which it is not by design